# Cannot install OpenJDK 1.8.0_45 through yum in RHEL 7.4

Tags: yum, java, rhel7

I am trying to install  `OpenJDK 1.8.0_45`  in my RHEL 7.4 VM through yum . Currently OpenJDK 1.7 is installed. 
 This is the output of release version of RHEL
 `rpm -qa |grep release`
`redhat-release-server-7.4-18.el7.x86_64`
What i want is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"`  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b13)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode).
```

When I tried `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` this is the error message I got:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager  
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.  
Bad id for repo: root@iotaasmon1 yum.repos.d, byte = @ 4  
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration  
Repository epel-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration  
Repository epel-source is listed more than once in the configuration  
No package java-1.8.0-openjdk available.  
Error: Nothing to do
```

`OpenJDK 1.8` is also not showing when  I did a `yum search`.

```
$ yum search openjdk  
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager  
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.  
Bad id for repo: root@iotaasmon1 yum.repos.d, byte = @ 4  
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration  
Repository epel-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration  
Repository epel-source is listed more than once in the configuration  
======================================================================================= N/S matched: openjdk ========================================================================================  
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment  
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 : The OpenJDK runtime environment without audio and video support  
openprops.noarch : An improved java.util.Properties from OpenJDK  
rh-thermostat16-thermostat.x86_64 : A monitoring and serviceability tool for OpenJDK  
thermostat1-thermostat.x86_64 : A monitoring and serviceability tool for OpenJDK  

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Can someone tell me how to install or upgrade to OpenJDK 1.8.
Kindly let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Can you show the output of `rpm -qa | grep release` ?

Comment: This is the output    rpm -qa |grep release    
redhat-release-server-7.4-18.el7.x86_64

Comment: I think your problem is this line: `This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register. `

Comment: @RPR Are you happy to use a CentOS repo rather than a RHEL one?